# Passing multiple arguments (other than data) to imap function for multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on a simple multiprocessing program in python where I am passing a dataset where each pair of the list will return the multiplication of them. But when I am trying to pass a string along with the dataset to specify the operation (basically if I pass 'add' it will add the pair of numbers and if I pass 'sub' then it will subtract the pair of numbers) then I am facing all kinds of errors. I tried to use the concept of partial function also but it was not that helpful. Here I am attaching my basic code if anybody can help me to modify the code then it will be a great help

```
import multiprocessing as mp

data=([1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],
[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]
,[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6])

def mul(x,y):
   return(x*y)

def data_param(data):
    return mul(data[0],data[1])
def pool_handler():
    #p1=input('enter plus/mul: ')
    p=mp.Pool(3)
    
    out=p.imap(data_param,data)
    for i in out:
        print(f"output: {i}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool_handler()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to pass the function along with its parameters:

```
...
def mul(x, y):
    return (x * y)

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def data_param(data):
    return data[2](data[0], data[1])

def pool_handler():

    p1 = input('enter plus/mul: ')
    if p1 == 'plus':
        func = add
    elif p1 == 'mul':
        func = mul
    else:
        print('Incorrect value')
        exit(1)

    p = mp.Pool(3)

    out = p.imap(data_param, ((elt[0], elt[1], func) for elt in data))
    for i in out:
        print(f"output: {i}")
```

Comment: Just thinking, both of us could probably drop the if/else loops and go with a dictionary instead. {"mul":mul, "div":div, "add":add, "sub":sub}. Obviously eval() is a dirty fix to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct solution to using imap, for multiprocessing I find apply_async more flexible in general use.

For the job here:

```
def mul(x,y):
    return(x*y)

def div(x,y):
    return(x/y)

def data_param(data, op):
    if op == "mul":
        return mul(data[0],data[1])
    elif op == "div":
        return div(data[0],data[1])
    else:
        print("You'll not get this print return in windows warning you of an error so beware!")


# ------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name___ == "__main__":

    data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]  #Cut down to reduce clutter

    op = "mul"

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    jobs = []

    for dataBit in data:
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(data_param, args=(dataBit, op)))

    results = [] 
    for jobBit in jobs:
        results = jobBit.get()

    pool.close()
```

Of course, you could probably directly use the operator passed into data_param with some clever footwork - but for the purposes of verbosity here, best left simple!

Comment: thanks for the help. But when we are using apply_async the order of the output won't match the order of the input data. Hence when I am using this methodology on another case then it is not working properly.

Comment: It will if you pull it out as per above.

I ordered the input into the list "jobs", and you retrieve your results from that list in the order they were inserted.

"jobs" could essentially be considered a buffer where completed work will reside until you access it in the order you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66866947/7152804 if you don't mind can you look into this