# how to pass parameters other than data through pool.imap() function for multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, image, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I am working on hyperspectral images. To reduce the noise from the image I am using wavelet transformation using pywt package. When I am doing this normally(serial processing) it's working smoothly. But when I am trying to implement parallel processing using multiple cores for wavelet transformation on the image, then I have to pass certain parameters like

1. wavelet family
2. thresholding  value
3. threshold technique (hard/soft)

But I am not able to pass these parameters using the pool object, I can pass only data as an argument when I am using the pool.imap(). But when I am using the pool.apply_async() it's taking much more time and also the order of the output is not the same. Here I am adding the code for reference:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time
from math import log10, sqrt
import pywt
import tifffile

def spec_trans(d,wav_fam,threshold_val,thresh_type):
  
  data=np.array(d,dtype=np.float64)
  data_dec=decomposition(data,wav_fam)
  data_t=thresholding(data_dec,threshold_val,thresh_type)
  data_rec=reconstruction(data_t,wav_fam)
  
  return data_rec

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    #input
    X=tifffile.imread('data/Classification/university.tif')
    #take paramaters
    threshold_val=float(input("Enter the value for image thresholding: "))
    print("The available wavelet functions:",pywt.wavelist())
    wav_fam=input("Choose a wavelet function for transformation: ")
    threshold_type=['hard','soft']
    print("The available wavelet functions:",threshold_type)
    thresh_type=input("Choose a type for threshholding technique: ")

    start=time.time()
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    jobs=[]
    for dataBand in xmp:
      jobs.append(p.apply_async(spec_trans,args=(dataBand,wav_fam,threshold_val,thresh_type)))
    transformedX=[]
    for jobBit in jobs:
      transformedX.append(jobBit.get())
    end=time.time()
    p.close()
```

Also when I am using the 'soft' technique for thresholding I am facing the following error:

```
C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywt\_thresholding.py:25: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  thresholded = data * thresholded
```

The results of serial execution and parallel execution would be more or less the same. But here I am getting slightly different results.
Any suggestion to modify the code will be helpful
Thank

Comment: ... and that is not giving you the answers in sequence? (this approach has worked for me for years).

Answer (score 0):

[This isn't a direct answer to the question, but a clearer follow up query than trying the below via the small comment box]

As a quick check, pass in an iterator counter to spec_trans and return it back out (as well as your result) - and push it into a separate list, transformedXseq or something - and then compare to your input sequence. i.e.

```
def spec_trans(d,wav_fam,threshold_val,thresh_type, iCount):

    data=np.array(d,dtype=np.float64)
    data_dec=decomposition(data,wav_fam)
    data_t=thresholding(data_dec,threshold_val,thresh_type)
    data_rec=reconstruction(data_t,wav_fam)

    return data_rec, iCount
```

and then within main

```
jobs=[]
iJobs = 0
for dataBand in xmp:
   jobs.append(p.apply_async(spec_trans,args=(dataBand,wav_fam,threshold_val,thresh_type, iJobs)))
   iJobs = iJobs + 1 

transformedX=[]
transformedXseq=[]
for jobBit in jobs:
    res = jobBit.get()
    transformedX.append(res[0])
    transformedXseq.append(res[1])
```

... and check the list transformedXseq to see if you've gathered the jobs back up in the sequence you submitted them. It *should* match!

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing the concept. I think the problem is not there in the pool object it's in another section. That's why I am still getting the warning for the 'soft' method of thresholding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `wav_fam`, `threshold_val` and `thresh_type` do not vary from call to call, first arrange for these arguments to be the *first* arguments to worker function `spec_trans`:

```py
def spec_trans(wav_fam, threshold_val, thresh_type, d):
```

Now I don't see where in your pool-creation block you have defined `xmp`, but presumably this is an iterable. You need to modify this code as follows:

```py
from functools import partial

def compute_chunksize(pool_size, iterable_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

if __name__ == '__main__':

    X=tifffile.imread('data/Classification/university.tif')
    #take paramaters
    threshold_val=float(input("Enter the value for image thresholding: "))
    print("The available wavelet functions:",pywt.wavelist())
    wav_fam=input("Choose a wavelet function for transformation: ")
    threshold_type=['hard','soft']
    print("The available wavelet functions:",threshold_type)
    thresh_type=input("Choose a type for threshholding technique: ")

    start=time.time()
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    # first 3 arguments to spec_trans will be wav_fam, threshold_val and thresh_type 
    worker = partial(spec_trans, wav_fam, threshold_val, thresh_type)
    suitable_chunksize = compute_chunksize(4, len(xmp))
    transformedX = list(p.imap(worker, xmp, chunksize=suitable_chunksize))
    end=time.time()
```

To obtain improved performance over using `apply_async`, you must use a "suitable chunksize" value with `imap`. Function `compute_chunksize` can be used for computing such a value based on the size of your pool, which is 4, and the size of the iterable being passed to `imap`, which would be `len(xmp)`. If the size of `xmp` is small enough such that the chunksize value computed is 1, I don't really see how `imap` would be significantly more performant over `apply_async`.

Of course, you might as well just use:

```py
    transformedX = p.map(worker, xmp)
```

And let the pool compute its own suitable chunksize. `imap` has an advantage over `map` when the iterable is very large and *not* already a list. For `map` to compute a suitable chunksize it would first have to convert the iterable to a list just to get its length and this could be memory inefficient. But if you know the length (or approximate length) of the iterable, then by using imap you can explicitly set a chunksize without having to convert the iterable to a list. The other advantage of `imap_unordered` over `map` is that you can process the results for the individual tasks as they become available whereas with `map` you only get results when all the submitted tasks are complete.

**Update**

If you want to catch possible exceptions thrown by individual tasks submitted to your worker function, then stick with using `imap`, and use the following code to iterate the results returned by `imap`:

```py
    #transformedX = list(p.imap(worker, xmp, chunksize=suitable_chunksize))
    transformedX = []
    results = p.imap(worker, xmp, chunksize=suitable_chunksize)
    import traceback
    while True:
        try:
            result = next(results)
        except StopIteration: # no more results
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception occurred:', e)
            traceback.print_exc() # print stacktrace
        else:
            transformedX.append(result)
```

Comment: multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\Desktop\MultiProcessing\code\mainP.py", line 40, in spec_trans
    data_dec=decomposition(data,wav_fam)
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\Desktop\MultiProcessing\code\mainP.py", line 17, in decomposition
    ddec=pywt.dwt(d,fam)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywt\_dwt.py", line 174, in dwt
    wavelet = _as_wavelet(wavelet)
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywt\_utils.py", line 23, in _as_wavelet
    wavelet = DiscreteContinuousWavelet(wavelet)
  File "pywt\_extensions\_pywt.pyx", line 321, in pywt._extensions._pywt.DiscreteContinuousWavelet
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
"""

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainP.py", line 138, in <module>
    waveletX = list(p.imap(worker, padded_X, chunksize=suitable_chunksize))
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 325, in <genexpr>
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
  File "C:\Users\Sawon\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 748, in next
    raise value
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Here I have pasted the total error message in three parts. When I am implementing the program in serial processing it's working nicely but when I am following the above-mentioned steps for multiprocessing then it's giving this error message.

Comment: It's a little difficult reading your stacktace this way, but the original exception appears to be somewhere in your code **'float' object has no attribute 'lower'**. If your call to the worker function using `imap` results in an exception, it will be reflected back to you when you iterate the results returned by the `imap` call. I will update the source to show you what I mean.

Comment: I've added an update. But warning: every one of your invocations of your worker function may be generating an exception, in which case you will get lots of exceptions and stacktraces. You have to figure out what is causing the exception in the invoked code.

Comment: Did you remember to redefine the argument order for function `spec_trans`?

Comment: yes, I redefined the order of the arguments for the function spec_trans. The warnings are showing for some occasions specially when I am using 'soft' mode for thresholding_type.